# Query value in nested json field

Tags: sql, postgresql

The table is called "process_flows" and the column of interest is called "results"

Process_flows Table:

| contact_uuid | result |
| --- | --- |
| 2f12c383-e131-4454-8713 | see text below |

The result column contains a nested json that looks like the sample below:

```
{
    "assessment_dialog": {
        "name": "Assessment Dialog",
        "value": "200",
        "category": "Success",
        "node_uuid": "dba105ed-57c6-4d1e-b8ca-2e312c7dd87b",
        "input": "POST https://dummy.com",
        "extra": {
            "choices": null,
            "formatType": "string",
            "max": null,
            "max_error": "",
            "min": null,
            "min_error": "",
            "pattern": "",
            "message": "What is your name?\n\n_Please type your name, or the name you want us to use._\n\nReply *BACK* to go to the previous question.",
            "explanations": "",
            "step": 3,
            "optionId": null,
            "path": "/assessments/ea0813fc-53d6-4b2f-b6a9-202432404e6d/dialog/next",
            "cardType": "INPUT",
            "description": "What is your name?",
            "pdf_media_id": "",
            "title": ""
        },
        "created_on": "2023-07-16T21:35:50.741325153Z"
    },
    "cardtype": {
        "name": "CardType",
        "value": "INPUT",
        "node_uuid": "80941c51-62c1-46a4-bbd1-7be50053aa1d",
        "created_on": "2023-07-16T21:35:50.741708602Z"
    },
    "cardtype_split": {
        "name": "cardType split",
        "value": "INPUT",
        "category": "Input",
        "node_uuid": "2147ad70-f472-4517-843b-c3456604e2e4",
        "input": "INPUT",
        "created_on": "2023-07-16T21:35:50.742223888Z"
    },
    "check_if_error": {
        "name": "Check if Error",
        "value": "FALSE",
        "category": "Other",
        "node_uuid": "3ead361b-e163-4576-9505-bc38c0964d7b",
        "input": "FALSE",
        "created_on": "2023-07-16T21:35:50.742535285Z"
    },
    "choicecontext": {
        "name": "choiceContext",
        "value": "",
        "node_uuid": "099c23dc-c24a-406b-aa66-32beea3ac026",
        "created_on": "2023-07-16T21:35:50.742409274Z"
    },
    "choices": {
        "name": "choices",
        "value": "",
        "node_uuid": "099c23dc-c24a-406b-aa66-32beea3ac026",
        "created_on": "2023-07-16T21:35:50.74240149Z"
    },
    "contact_reply": {
        "name": "contact reply",
        "value": "1",
        "category": "Other",
        "node_uuid": "f17e88aa-62a2-4097-8a44-1c21a2fe9a51",
        "input": "1",
        "created_on": "2023-07-16T21:35:50.565141173Z"
    },
    "description": {
        "name": "Description",
        "value": "What is your name?",
        "node_uuid": "80941c51-62c1-46a4-bbd1-7be50053aa1d",
        "created_on": "2023-07-16T21:35:50.741878847Z"
    },
    "error": {
        "name": "error",
        "value": "",
        "node_uuid": "61fb733d-793a-4792-9bcf-00a8f3673dd0",
        "created_on": "2023-07-16T21:35:50.565275784Z"
    },
    "explanations": {
        "name": "explanations",
        "value": "",
        "node_uuid": "d7362c4e-feb7-4264-b666-de0ed5551f71",
        "created_on": "2023-07-16T21:35:50.742132444Z"
    },
    "formattype": {
        "name": "formatType",
        "value": "string",
        "node_uuid": "099c23dc-c24a-406b-aa66-32beea3ac026",
        "created_on": "2023-07-16T21:35:50.742261153Z"
    },
    "iserror": {
        "name": "iserror",
        "value": "FALSE",
        "node_uuid": "d868ea8d-f7cd-4a34-8392-06c537c816ab",
        "created_on": "2023-07-16T21:35:50.741672008Z"
    },
    "max": {
        "name": "max",
        "value": "",
        "node_uuid": "099c23dc-c24a-406b-aa66-32beea3ac026",
        "created_on": "2023-07-16T21:35:50.742298674Z"
    },
    "max_error": {
        "name": "max error",
        "value": "",
        "node_uuid": "099c23dc-c24a-406b-aa66-32beea3ac026",
        "created_on": "2023-07-16T21:35:50.742327262Z"
    },
    "message": {
        "name": "message",
        "value": "What is your name?\n\n_Please type your name, or the name you want us to use._\n\nReply *BACK* to go to the previous question.",
        "node_uuid": "80941c51-62c1-46a4-bbd1-7be50053aa1d",
        "created_on": "2023-07-16T21:35:50.741907836Z"
    },
    "min": {
        "name": "min",
        "value": "",
        "node_uuid": "099c23dc-c24a-406b-aa66-32beea3ac026",
        "created_on": "2023-07-16T21:35:50.742361422Z"
    },
    "min_error": {
        "name": "min error",
        "value": "",
        "node_uuid": "099c23dc-c24a-406b-aa66-32beea3ac026",
        "created_on": "2023-07-16T21:35:50.742392134Z"
    },
    "msisdn": {
        "name": "msisdn",
        "value": "2349039756628",
        "node_uuid": "87b80fd5-6b02-4044-95a0-949ce2986c2b",
        "created_on": "2023-07-16T21:14:31.229769036Z"
    },
    "optionid": {
        "name": "OptionId",
        "value": "",
        "node_uuid": "80941c51-62c1-46a4-bbd1-7be50053aa1d",
        "created_on": "2023-07-16T21:35:50.741776681Z"
    },
    "path": {
        "name": "path",
        "value": "/assessments/ea0813fc-53d6-4b2f-b6a9-202432404e6d/dialog/next",
        "node_uuid": "80941c51-62c1-46a4-bbd1-7be50053aa1d",
        "created_on": "2023-07-16T21:35:50.741811755Z"
    },
    "pattern": {
        "name": "Pattern",
        "value": "",
        "node_uuid": "099c23dc-c24a-406b-aa66-32beea3ac026",
        "created_on": "2023-07-16T21:35:50.742443817Z"
    },
    "pdf_media_id": {
        "name": "PDF Media ID",
        "value": "",
        "node_uuid": "80941c51-62c1-46a4-bbd1-7be50053aa1d",
        "created_on": "2023-07-16T21:35:50.741936948Z"
    },
    "resources": {
        "name": "resources",
        "value": "",
        "node_uuid": "f0d7ffc8-dd77-4a43-a382-ffce6daf6ca3",
        "created_on": "2023-07-16T21:22:05.441680904Z"
    },
    "roadblock": {
        "name": "Roadblock",
        "value": "INPUT",
        "category": "Other",
        "node_uuid": "c9bb3073-b117-4372-a8ae-6a58f3462f39",
        "input": "INPUT",
        "created_on": "2023-07-16T21:35:50.741655325Z"
    },
    "step": {
        "name": "step",
        "value": "3",
        "node_uuid": "80941c51-62c1-46a4-bbd1-7be50053aa1d",
        "created_on": "2023-07-16T21:35:50.741747967Z"
    },
    "title": {
        "name": "Title",
        "value": "",
        "node_uuid": "80941c51-62c1-46a4-bbd1-7be50053aa1d",
        "created_on": "2023-07-16T21:35:50.741839141Z"
    },
    "value": {
        "name": "value",
        "value": "1",
        "node_uuid": "61fb733d-793a-4792-9bcf-00a8f3673dd0",
        "created_on": "2023-07-16T21:35:50.565266618Z"
    },
    "webhook_failure_count": {
        "name": "Webhook Failure Count",
        "value": "0",
        "node_uuid": "87b80fd5-6b02-4044-95a0-949ce2986c2b",
        "created_on": "2023-07-16T21:14:31.229591231Z"
    }
}
```

It's a lot of data.

I'm trying to access the "step" value in results:

```
"step":3
```

I want a result like this:

| Step |
| --- |
| 3 |

My query:

```
select contact_uuid, results->>'step' as step, 
from process_flows
```

I only need to see step in results and not every value in the nested json.

My query:

```
SELECT results -> 'extra' ->> 'step'
FROM process_flows
```

Error:

```
Error running query: operator does not exist: text -> unknown LINE 1: ...Queue: queries, Query ID: adhoc */ SELECT results -> 'extra'... ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I'm only trying to access the "step" key-value in the json.
Thanks

Comment: even after make your json readable, it is not clear to see how you get your wated resultset, only showing the json nodes that are vital for the query, would help imensly

Comment: What's wrong with your query? Undesired results? If so, show them. Error messages? If so, show them. (Is the result column a string datatype or a json datatype?)

Comment: You have omitted "'assessment_dialog". `select (results -> 'assessment_dialog' -> 'extra' ->> 'step')::integer from process_flows;`

Answer (score 1):

You have two keys named "step," one at the top level with a value that is a JSON object, and one with an integer value nested within the JSON object with key "assessment_dialog". I'm assuming only the latter is desired. The following query uses an explicit path to extract the desired value as an integer:

```
SELECT contract_uuid, (results #>> '{assessment_dialog, extra, step}')::integer AS step
  FROM process_flows;
```

Comment: Thanks. I've posted the solution. I had to cast 'results'.
```cast(results AS jsonb)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to cast the field to jsonb:

```
SELECT cast(results AS jsonb) -> 'assessment_dialog' -> 'extra' ->> 'step' AS step,
```